# Joomla 1.5 extension for adding trips and email an offer

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I'm working on a travel site and am interested in adding some functionality so that visitors can easily click on a travel destination and add it in a "bag", pretty much like a shopping cart on traditional e-commerce websites. When a few destinations are added the customer should be able to type their own text along with the picked destinations and then send an offer by clicking a button.
A travel guide will then receive the form data to customize a trip for the potential customer.

Every destination in Joomla has its own article and therefore need some sort of button that the user can click to add trip to the "bag". If this functionality is inserted in the article by some piece of code or if it's a module in the sidebar doesn't really matter.

I have tried using "SimpleCaddy" for Joomla. I have modified it but I find it really hard to turn it into something useful.

I would like to know how to best proceed? Are there perhaps any extensions, (commercial or non-commercial doesn't matter), that can get the job done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most definitley there are.  You tagged you're using joomla 1.5, Virtuemart is a great e-commerce solution for that version.  Hugely popular, well supported, large community extremely customizable... the downside is that it can be very complex if you're not sure what's going on.  Simple Caddy is a great one for something really lightweight and easy to get up and running quickly - but it lacks any sort of advanced features.

Unfortunately in my experience finding one that blends between 'lightweight and easy', and 'full featured and complex' is very difficult.  you may also want to try JoomShopping however - I've recently installed it on a site and had great success with it.  It was really straight forward, setup was not too bad and getting it configured just took a bit of trial and error (unfortunately there are no real good tool-tips or anything to help you figure out exactly what does what on the back-end).

Those are my two recommendations; Virtuemart or Joomshopping.  They both have shoppingcart features which I'm sure you could easily modify to be the users 'bag'.  Both seem to have a pretty good/proven track record and a well rounded community.  I think either way you'll be satisfied, but it does sound like SimpleCaddy may come up 'just short' of what you're needing.

Comment: Yes I'm using Joomla 1.5. I'd just like to clarify that I am not looking for a full-fledged e-commerce solution, I just want the the shopping cart-like functionality where it remembers the items you have picked so that you can easily "check out", which in this case would be a button that says "send offer" or similar. I don't need prices, currency or payment or anything. I will check out JoomShopping though and see if it can be tuned for my needs. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Hmmm, you MAY be able to setup something with a crafty installation of Chronoforms as well (but I'm not sure how that would be done exactly... it would probably require a lot of work/customization) but it could all tie together into a form that gets 'submitted'.  You're right, a full fledged e-commerce doesn't sound like your need.. more of just something to remember selections and submit them.  The guys at Chronoform are REALLY good at helping out - check out their forums and hit up their dev's (they check the boards daily) - they may be able to help too.

Comment: I spent many hours on this and it turns out SimpleCaddy could get the job done, but it requires manually changing a few lines of code. At one occasion a single little dot ruined the whole output. I would say if one knows a little something about PHP, then SimpleCaddy is a really good foundation.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for posting back!  Glad you got it worked out!